# Set openDNS on ubuntu server 12.04.3

Tags: networking

How can i set to use openDNS on my ubuntu server? I am virtualizing for improvement at home, so i don't want to change router configuration etc..

I tried setting it on the file `/etc/resolv.conf` but every time I reboot my virtual server it overwrites my changes.

Comment: What are you improving at home? I set OpenDNS as the DNS server on my router once, something like five years ago, and I haven't touched it since. I can't imagine an improvement over flawless.

Comment: A local server for home, so try some services like apache2, vsftpd and other services, im still studing at school.. That day i learned how to give an IP to a network card on a linux host at school, the command was ifconfig eth0 ecc.. But it doesn't enought for me, i wanted to give a static IP, change the dns servers and don't use the router DHCP for the server IP. I tried to add opendns on the router but i cannot do it, beacuse Telecom Italia router doesn't permit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ifup to configure the interface over which you will access the OpenDNS nameserver then add a `dns-nameservers` option to the definition of that interface in /etc/network/interfaces specifying the IP address of the OpenDNS nameserver.

If you use NetworkManager to configure the connection over which you will access the OpenDNS nameserver then add the IP address of the OpenDNS nameserver to network indicator | Edit Connections... | Edit... | IPv4 Settings | Additional DNS servers.